# Same UI for all platforms in Mvvmcross Xamarin

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, mvvmcross

**Hello All, Can i code one UI for all platforms using Mvvm Cross framework in Xamarin?**

Like i code for a generic UI which can generated for different platforms Android,IOS,Windows.

I saw Xamarin Forms giving some thing like this , but what about MVVMCross.

Comment: I suggest to get to know more about Xamarin.Forms it has it own MVVM framework built in. With MVVMCross it's not possible to reuse UI code.

Answer (score 0):

No, Mvvmcross doesn't provide UI automagically. View is platform specific while models and viewmodels are platform independent.
With Forms all three are platform independent. To make this work Forms added another layer, called Renderer (which is platform specific). Out of the box there is a bunch of renderers, then there is 3rd party community (specially Forms Labs) and finally, you can make your own renderers or extend existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

So if i conclude in simple sencario , since xamarin forms uses Mvvm so its better to use xamarin forms instead of mvvmcross for one single Ui